# Webforms : Access theme value by themeID in code

Tags: asp.net, webforms, themes

I have inherited an old webforms project with themes and skin-files And I'm in the process of slowly migrating it.

As a part of this process I'd like to get an image from a skinfile from code.
Lets assume the skin-file contains these posts:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" SkinID="iconSearch" ImageUrl="Images/Icons/search.gif" />
<asp:Image runat="server" SkinID="iconCancel" ImageUrl="Images/Icons/cancel.gif" />
```

Now I want to get the full path of the "iconSearch" image and use it directly in the .ASPX file. Something like;

```
<div style="background-image:url(<%= someFunctionToResolveImageURL("iconSearch") %>);width :16px; height:16px;"></div>
```

should resolve to something like :

```
<div style="background-image: url('/app_themes/default/Images/Icons/mail_thanks.gif';); width: 16px; height: 16px;"></div>
```

But I simply cant find a way to get the image url when having the SkinID.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your image control(s) don't have a id, so you have to search the controls, and look for a "image" control, and then check if that "SkinID" will match what you are looking for.

So, say we have this:

```
        <asp:Image SkinID="iconSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Content/R2.jpg" />

        <div style="background-image:url('<%= iResolve(Me.Page, "iconSearch") %>');
        width :128px;height:128px;border:solid">
```

Then a public function in that web page could resolve (get) the image url like this:

```
Public Function iResolve(MyCtrl As Control, sImage As String) As String

    ' find this control in current page
    For Each cT As Control In MyCtrl.Controls
        If cT.GetType.ToString = GetType(Image).ToString Then
            Dim MyImage As Image = cT
            If MyImage.SkinID = sImage Then
                Return MyImage.ImageUrl
            End If
        End If
        Dim sU As String = iResolve(cT, sImage)
        If sU <> "" Then Return sU
    Next
    return ""
End Function
```

so, you can "cobble" some routine that would search by SkinID as opposed to control id.

If I run the above, I get this:

[image]

So, you can search by SkinID - and say not a control ID on the page.

But, you need to traverse the controls on the page for that kind of search.
So, the above little recursive routine does seem to do the trick.